# How is FindBugs Unwritten Public Field (UWF) determined?

Tags: java, findbugs

I have two classes:

```
class Foo {
    // some stuff      
}

class Bar extends Foo {
   public String a;
   // other stuff
}
```

When I run findBugs on this code, there are no warnings.

I want to refactor and move the field A from Bar to Foo, like so:

```
class Foo {
    public String a;
    // some stuff
}

class Bar extends Foo {
   // other stuff
}
```

But now findBugs complains with UWF Unwritten public or protected field.

Other things about my system:

- These classes exist in a gradle project called "dtos"
- The field "a" is being written to in a gradle project called "main"
- There is no @SuppressFBWarnings set on the objects
- There is a few @Json (jackson) annotations in various places in Bar, but none that refer to the field "a"
- There is a exclude filter file for findBugs, but it doesn't mention UWF

How does findBugs determine UWF? Where are all the places it looks for supressions? What are all the third-party libraries that findBugs knows about (it knows about Jackson) that would cause UWF to be supressed? Any other ideas?

Comment: I guessing, but if you somewhere have `bar.a = ""`, then field `a` of class `Bar` is assigned, and findBugs detects that. When you moved it to class `Foo`, it doesn't consider `bar.a` an assigning of `foo.a`, even though it is. Bug in findBugs. Of course, if you stop using public fields, as is generally considered the norm, and always use a setter method, then this issue may go away.

Comment: @Andreas The only place in the "dtos" project where `bar.a` is written to is in junit tests.  Does findbugs consider that to be a valid write? I would hope not.  Either findBugs has a bug which looks at test code as valid code AND it has the bug which you described.  Or something else is suppressing the original `bar.a`


Also, to your comment about using private with setters/getters.  We had a big debate and settled on public, since these are inter-tier objects and the model for them should not change.  I don't want to get into that discussion here.

Comment: The source code for FindBugs is freely available.  That will tell you how it does the checks, and answer your other questions.  Note that the implementation *may be different in different versions of FindBugs*.

Comment: @StephenC I understand that I could read through the source, I was hoping that someone else knew the answer already.

Comment: @Nathan - That is highly unlikely.

Comment: @Nathan Unless you configure Findbugs to analyze test classes, it won't look at them at all, so I doubt that's what's causing the discrepancy.